# Add title to the plotly legend

Tags: r, plot, plotly

In the following example how can i add a title to the legend in plot_ly for R ?

```
mtcars %>%   plot_ly(x = ~disp, y = ~mpg, color = ~factor(cyl), size = ~wt) %>%   add_markers(
    hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~paste("Displacement = ", disp, "\nMiles Per Gallon = ", mpg)   ) %>%   layout(title ="Custom Hover Text")
```

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I know is to use an annotation and add it to the plot. Like this:

```
legendtitle <- list(yref='paper',xref="paper",y=1.05,x=1.1, text="Cylinders",showarrow=F)

mtcars %>%  plot_ly(x = ~disp, y = ~mpg, color = ~factor(cyl), size = ~wt) %>%   
  add_markers(  hoverinfo = "text",
                text = ~paste("Displacement=",disp, "\nMiles Per Gallon = ", mpg)) %>%   
  layout(title ="Custom Hover Text", annotations=legendtitle )
```

Yielding:

[image]

It is a bit tricky to place the legend title though, not sure if this placement would always work.

Another way would be to use ggplot and ggplotly of course, and let ggplot figure it out.

Answer (score 10):

This functionality has since been included within the `layout` function in the `legend` option. There's a sub-option called `title` within which you can supply a list that includes the text.

```
mtcars %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~disp, y = ~mpg, color = ~factor(cyl), size = ~wt) %>% 
  add_markers(hoverinfo = "text",
              text = ~paste("Displacement = ", disp, "\nMiles Per Gallon = ", mpg)   ) %>% 
  layout(title = "Custom Hover Text", 
         legend = list(title = list(text = "<b>Cylinders</b>"))) # TITLE HERE
```

Comment: Strange enough, this does not seem to work when the color is not discrete. If `color = ~drat`, for example.

Comment: @mic please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at @mics comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62161572/9841389), there still seems to be some confusion regarding the legend title - so lets unravel things:

Once we are passing factors to `plot_ly()`'s color parameter

```
color = ~factor(drat)
```

plotly will create a legend (for discrete / categorial data) and we can use `layout()` to set the legend title:

```
fig_discrete <- mtcars %>%
  plot_ly(
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers",
    x = ~ disp,
    y = ~ mpg,
    color = ~ factor(cyl),
    size = ~ wt,
    fill = "",
    hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~ paste("Displacement = ", disp, "\nMiles Per Gallon = ", mpg)
  ) %>% layout(title = "Custom Hover Text", legend = list(title = list(text = "<b>Cylinders</b>")))
fig_discrete

# plotly_json(fig_discrete)
# navigate:
# layout.legend.title.text
```

[image: result_1]

However, once we pass numeric data to `plot_ly()`'s color parameter

```
color = ~drat
```

plotly will create a colorbar (for continuous data) and we can use `colorbar()` to set the colorbar title:

```
fig_continuous <- mtcars %>%
  plot_ly(
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers",
    x = ~ disp,
    y = ~ mpg,
    color = ~ drat,
    marker = list(size = ~ wt * 3),
    hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~ paste("Displacement = ", disp, "\nMiles Per Gallon = ", mpg)
  ) %>% layout(title = "Custom Hover Text") %>% colorbar(title = "<i>Rear Axle Ratio</i>")
fig_continuous

# plotly_json(fig_continuous)
# navigate:
# data[0].marker.colorbar.title
# and
# data[1].marker.colorbar.title
```

[image: result_2]

For further information please see the [according documentation](https://plotly.com/r/discrete-color/).